# Facebook individual tone

Tags: facebook-messenger

Is there a way in Facebook messenger to customize the message tone for individual people? I can change the Default tone for everyone but I want to change for individual people.

Answer (score 0):

If by 'tone' you mean colour, then you sure can: Go to Messages Tab -> (Contact) -> Press the  in the top right corner -> Scroll down until you see 'colour', enjoy the colours.
-Daniel ✓